# How to merge the git branch that was span off from my branch?

Tags: git

I have an issue branch A4 that was spun off from the master.  My lead created a branch A5 based on A4 and made some changes.  Now I need to merge his changes back to A4.

What is the best procedure to do this?

Comment: The git book has [a chapter on branching on merging](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging). Does that help out?

Comment: Yes, helpful, but just in case a good solution in an answer is appreciated

Comment: You get better answers if you first show us what you've tried (and how it failed, or how the behavior was different than you expected based on your understanding of the documentation). If nothing else, this prevents us from suggesting that you do something that you have in fact already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case all you have to do to merge changes on A5 into A4 is:

```
git checkout A4
git merge A5
```

This will replay the changes done in A5 onto A4.

Comment: This assumes you have the latest versions of A4 and A5 present in your local repo.